# Is there any 'Hard-Sigmoid' approximations for the Signum function?

Tags: functions, approximation

I found numerous sigmoid-curve approximations for signum function. Some are really good, but a hard-sigmoid could be better, so does any approximations falling in that category exist?

And if a 'hard-sigmoid' approximation do exist, will that be better than it's sigmoid-counterparts?

Comment: What do you mean by “hard-sigmoid”? Note that, if $S(x)$ is a sigmoid function centered at $x=0$, then $S(kx)$ is also such a sigmoid function but with slope $k S’(0)$ at the center. So by making $k$ bigger you can make a sigmoid which is as steep as you want. (In particular, if you pick some $x\lessgtr 0$ and let $k\to +\infty$, then $S(kx)\to \pm 1$.)

Comment: @semiclassical, for example a f(kx') that gives me this (https://imgur.com/a/6XjoBrR) at k = 1 ('hard sigmoid), and there's f(kx) that gives me this (https://imgur.com/a/bimRBrk) at k = 1 (sigmoid). We can see that f(x') really is sharp even when $k=1$. So is f(x') or f(x) a better approximation?

Comment: You need to decide what you mean by “better”. What measure are you using for determining the deviation between the original function and the approximation? Without knowing that, there is no way to answer your question.

Comment: I use the fact that which function which where the most values gets their desired signum value is a better approximate. A hard-sigmoid does this better than a regular sigmoid right?